# Sagepay: easy way to tell whether server, form or direct integration is being used

Tags: opayo

Need to get started on an upgrade from 2.23 to v3. Is there an easy way to tell whether server, form or direct integration is already being used, and therefore which of the support docs/kits I should be following.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the URL you are posting the transaction registration post to. vspdirect-register.vsp for Direct, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Rik! So am I safe to assume from this line:    
   `$strPurchaseURL="https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp"; `
That it is currently using form integration?

Comment: Yes you are. Fortunately, 2.23 to 3.00 isn't too onerous. At the bare minimum, you'll need to update the protocol version, and make sure you are using AES encryption. There are some extra response fields, too, so best make sure you can handle / ignore those as required.